# What exactly is the difference between Mindfulness and Concentration

Tags: buddha

What exactly is the difference between Mindfulness and Concentration (I have seen different views on this topic so I would be happy if you could help me understand it)

Comment: This is very broad. Are you asking about English words? Or about Pali terms "sati" and "samadhi"? Do you have any texts in mind, when asking this? Focus on Theravada or Mahayana, or all schools? Are you asking this in context of some kind of practice you're attempting to do? etc.

Comment: Let's add more details before people jump to answers, and then will reopen.

Comment: Mindfulness ('sati'; literally 'to remember'; 'not be forgetful') means to "bring to mind & keep in mind' the task you must do. 'Samadhi' means 'collectedness' or 'to gather together' and refers to the mind in one-focused or non-distracted on its talk. The role of mindfulness in Buddhist meditation is to remember to keep the mind free from unwholesome mental states & wrong views. When mindfulness performs its  role, the result is "samadhi", namely, the mind unified with mental purity & the meditation objects (such as breathing) that naturally come into awareness when the mind is pure.

Comment: I would say mindfulness is all encompassing, while concentration implies a narrowing of focus.  .